# PrimeNG DataTable filling out the data issue

Tags: json, angular, primeng

I have an issue with filling the DataTable with data from JSON. I cannot access the one of the JSON's field which is an array. Currently, it returns `[object Object]` instead of proper data. I create the cols dynamically in component with `ngOnInit`.

Simplified code:

**Vehicle.component.ts**

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {

  cols: any[];
  cols2: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'vehicle_id', header: "Vehicle ID" },
      { field: 'dallassettings', header: 'Dallas settings' },
      { field: 'dallasupdated', header: 'Dallas updated' },
      { field: 'dallas_list', header: 'Dallas list' }
    ];
    this.cols2 = [
      { field: 'number', header: 'Number' },
      { field: 'auth', header: 'Auth' },
      { field: 'dallas_list', header: 'Dallas list' }
    ]; //testing out other possibilities
  }

  public vehicles: GeneralVehicle[];

  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService, private router: Router) {
    this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
      this.vehicles = vehicle;
    });
  }

interface GeneralVehicle {
  status: number;
  dallases: Vehicle[];
}

interface Vehicle {
  vehicle_id: number;
  dallassettings: string;
  dallasupdated: string;
  dallas_list: DallasList[];
}

interface DallasList {
  number: number;
  auth: number;
}
```

**Vehicle.service.ts**

```
export class VehicleService {
    private defUrl = 'dummy.url';

constructor(private http: Http) { }
getVehicle(username?: string, password?: string) {
    const url = (!username || !password) ? this.defUrl : 'dummy.url' + username + '/' + Md5.hashStr(password);
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

**vehicle.html**

```
    <div *ngIf="vehicles">
        <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases">
            <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
    </div>

<!--Testig out other possibilities-->
    <div *ngIf="vehicles">
        <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallas_list">
            <p-column *ngFor="let col2 of cols2" [field]="col2.field" [header]="col2.header"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
    </div>
```

Current output:
[image]

When I try to get the `number` and `auth` from `dallas_list` array:

[image]

This is how the JSON looks like:

```
{
"status": 0,
"dallases": [{
    "vehicle_id": 17954,
    "dallassettings": "3",
    "dallasupdated": "False",
    "dallas_list": [{
        "number": 666111222,
        "auth": 3
    }, {
        "number": 666777888,
        "auth": 4
    }, {
        "number": 123454321,
        "auth": 4
    }]
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm interested only in data inside the `dallases` field.

Expected cols output: vehicle_id, dallassettings, dallasupdated, number, auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json object the dallases_list is under dallases. so after accessing dallases from that index you need to access the dallases_list

```
<div *ngIf="vehicles">
        <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases">
            <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
    </div>

<!--Testig out other possibilities-->
    <div *ngIf="vehicles">
        <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases[0].dallas_list">
            <p-column *ngFor="let col2 of cols2" [field]="col2.field" [header]="col2.header"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
    </div>
```

Comment: That solutions works, but do you have any idea how to merge this into one table? The multiplied numbers could be one row separated with semicolons. I suppose I cannot use `[value]="vehicles.dallases[0].dallas_list"` inside `<p-column>` markup, so it's kinda difficult to make it work. Do you think `RowGroup` would somehow solve this?

Comment: Check the link https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowexpansion

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've got a nested array there so how do you want to display that information in the datatable?

Each vehicle in the 'dallases' array then has a child list (dallas_list) containing multiple entries of 'number/auth'.

You could transform your list to flatten that out so you have 1 row for each entry in 'dallas_list'.

Alternatively, the PrimeNG datatable supports [row expansions](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowexpansion) - so you could keep the data in the current form and have the expansion template display the number/auth details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked this out - I suppose I'll use it together with Vingresh's solution as it's the only way to make it work as it should be.